# having multiple repositories in controller how to use constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In repository pattern if i have multiple repositories ,how should i use them in the controller?one by one should be added in the constructor?if no,whats the right way?

```
IStudentRepository _repository;
ICoursRepository _courseRepo;

public HomeController(IStudentRepository _repository,ICoursRepository _courseRepo)
{
    this._repository = _repository;
    this._courseRepo = _courseRepo;
}
```

now imagine i need to inject more repositories ,it will become a nightmare!

Comment: It becoming a nightmare is an indication the controller is doing too much.

Comment: Normally you would have a service that has all the repositories it needs, and the controller asks for the service(s) rather than the repositories

Comment: You probably need multiple controllers with different routes or a service/dedicated repository in case you need aggregated data.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto but if i dont want to use service,what should i do to manage it?

Comment: You could inject the repositories in the actions that need them instead of to the entire controller, depending on your business requirements

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit does unit of work and generic repository solve the issue?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto can you take an example here please im a bit confused

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core's dependency injection or what framework exactly?

Comment: No, that's just a way of implementing your repository. It's hard to give you advice since we don't know any requirement. Also, these kind of questions are out of scope of stackoverflow.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto MVC 5 and repository pattern

Comment: Are `IStudentRepository` and `ICourseRepository` really just wrappers around EF's `DbSet<Student>` and `DbSet<Course>`? If so scrap the design and just inject a single `DbContext` instance into your controller instead.

Comment: @Igor i was creating a repository pattern using mvc,one repository per class,but i dont as the number of repositories increas,a,b,c,....i should add constructor accordingly ?

Comment: Don't use a pattern just to use the pattern.